# What's the word for a sentence structured like "something is to something as something is to something else"

Tags: meaning, grammar

How can we describe it?

> Immensely is to hugely as steady is to regular.

Comment: if this is the kind of question often found on English tests, it's most likely called an *analogy*

Comment: 'Proportionality' is used not only in maths to describe the a : b :: c : d 4-component relation.

Answer (score 2):

Analogy.

> A comparison made between one thing and another for the purpose of explanation or clarification.

[OED](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/7030;jsessionid=B1AA83A209BFBC80C0D1668DD574D3D5)

These are very popular in standardized tests.